# With python How to get only the indices of list items and use them as a variable in f-string

Tags: python, list, selenium, enumerate

I'm trying to get selenium to click specific buttons on a website.
To do that I need the indices of list items to be a variable in a f-string.
Is there a neat way to access the indices of that list and declare them a variable? I know you can get both values, index and itemvalue of a list by enumerate, but maybe theres another way than converting the index strings into integers and work on with these.
Thats what I got so far:

```
T3 = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='tabelle_merkliste']/tbody/tr[position()<25]/td[10]/img/following::td[2]")

verf3string = []

for i in T3:                     # retrieve textelement
    print(i.text)
    textelement = i.text.split('/')  
    plätze = textelement[0]      # only retrieve first position   of string
    print(plätze)

    verf3string.append(plätze)   #safe text in list


print(verf3string)

for i in range(len(verf3string)): # converting string list into list of integers to be able to compare numbers by </>
    verf3 = (verf3string[i])
    print(verf3)




for i in (verf3):
    if i > 0:
       x = verf3.index(i)
       browser.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="tabelle_merkliste"]/tbody/tr{x}/td{y}/img').click()

#this gives me the error TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

By Any help is appreciated, thanks!

By enumerate I meant using it to retrieve indeces. It gives me the index plus value.

```
for index, value in enumerate(test_list):
print(index, value)
```

(

Comment: maybe `list.index`?

Comment: @Brian Please don't change the author's intent. Your edit removed important context, so I rolled it back. Either way, the question's not totally clear and your edit didn't really help to clarify it IMHO.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking exactly. What do you mean by "converting the index strings into integers"? Indexes of a list already are integers, not strings. Could you show us your code using `enumerate()`? That might help clarify the problem. Please also provide a [mre] with complete code, i.e. definitions of `index` and `verf3`. And is Selenium actually relevant to the problem, or does it just happen to be what you're working with? Like, could you demonstrate the problem using `print()` in place of `browser.find_element_by_xpath()`? For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: I see the question was written a bit hasty, I'm sorry for that! Does not add to being new to python haha. Also I saw the indeces are not printed as strings, I misread that! Selenium doesn't add any useful information, I added it only for context reasons. Thanks for your patience @ wjandrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just retrieve the index of the item in a list (called 'array' here) like this:

```
x = array.index(i)
```

Or just do it in the f-string:

```
f'//*[@id="tabelle_merkliste"]/tbody/tr{array.index(i)}/td{y}  /img'
```